# converting an autogluon timeseries dataframe to a pandas df

Tags: pandas, autogluon

I have a autogluon timeseries dataframe, that contains forecasts for a few days out.

I want to write the forecast back to a DB, so it can be vizualized on a dashboard.
The issue is that the timeseries dataframe has the `item_id`, `timestamp`,`value` format where the `item_id` appears more like an index and not a column (hence only one entry for the entirety of the forecast.

Is there a way I can convert it back to a regular pandas df?

I am using the `ts_df.to_pandas()` but apparently its not supported anymore.
Thanks!